# Formal properties of limits of $\infty$-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, infinity-categories

I want to understand the usage of $\infty$-categories
in the proof of Proposition 10.5 in the Condensed Mathematics
lecture notes available here: https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Condensed.pdf .

I am struggling with the following sentence in the second paragraph:

> It is formal that $F$ has a right adjoint, which is given by
> taking a collection of objects $M_I \in \mathcal{C}_I$,
> compatible under localization, to their limit
> $\varprojlim M_I \in \mathcal{C}$.

I would like to understand where this comes from. That is,

1. Why are the objects of $\varprojlim_{I}\mathcal{C}_I$
   given by collections of objects $M_{I}\in\mathcal{C}_I$,
   compatible under localization? I am aware of Corollary 3.3.3.2
   in Lurie's Higher Topos Theory, which gives an explicit
   description of limits in the $\infty$-category of
   $\infty$-categories. However,
   I do not understand how this relates to the Proposition
   10.5 in the Condensed Maths lecture notes, nor how to
   use Lurie's result in practise.
2. Where exactly does the right adjoint described in
   Proposition 10.5 come from?

Many thanks!

Comment: The general limit is covered in Lurie's Higher Algebra 5.2.2.36, but it is easier to see an example how it is used: Lemma D.3.5.5 in Lurie's Spectral Algebraic Geometry. The case in Condensed.pdf is particularly simple because all maps are localizations (of categories).

Comment: @Z. M many thanks for the references! Could you please explain how the (b) in the proof of Lemma D.3.5.5 in SAG is related to HA 5.2.2.36?

Comment: The (b) in the proof of [SAG, D.3.5.5] is checking the condition (b) in [HA, 5.2.2.36]. Checking that $\phi$ is an equivalence for every $i$ is showing that they form coCartesian edges. The construction per se is a relative limit (note that this coCartesian fibration is in fact also a Cartesian fibration): some result in HTT reduces relative colimits to colimits on fibers, but I don't find it now.

Comment: @Z.M Many thanks!

Comment: @Z.M So I thought about [HA, 5.2.2.36] for a while, and I am still not precisely sure about the details in the application to [SAG, D.3.5.5]. Also, I do not think this answers my original questions. Maybe could you please clarify again to me how to answer my two questions 1 and 2 from above? To be really precise here, I want to understand how to realise objects in the limit $\infty$-category $\varprojlim_{I}\mathcal{C}_{I}$ as diagrams $S\rightarrow\cal{C}$, in light of HTT 3.3.3.2.

Comment: You seem to stick to HTT 3.3.3.2, but it does not seem to be anything concrete to me (maybe I understand too little about straightening/unstraightening). To determine objects of a limit, it suffices to determine those in the limit of maximal groupoids, which has the description that you wrote.

Comment: I was referring to a general principal in HA which is sufficiently general to check most descent property that I encounter, including this one. I am not trying to precisely addressing your questions, but making a comment from a "user" point of view of HA. In Scholze's notes, he somehow reproduces some logic in the proof of HA 5.2.2.36, but I would treat this as an easily-used blackbox, thus not trying to explain these right adjoints.